# Why is my User Login no longer working after upgrading to Symfony3

Tags: authentication, doctrine-orm, dao, symfony

I came along a strange Problem with Symfony 3.
Under Symfony 2 everyhting worked out of the Box (Login).
But under Symfony 3 it doesn't validate at all.
The Doctrine Layer is not Loading my User Object nor the Repository.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, short update.
I was able to fix this and would like to share what happened.
After Debuging the complete Login Prozess I stumbled accross the main cause for not beeing able to login.

```
<?php
    // src/AppBundle/Entity/UserRepository.php
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

    class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
    {
        public function loadUserByUsername($username)
        {
            $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
                ->setParameter('username', $username)
                ->setParameter('email', $username)
                ->getQuery()
                ->getOneOrNullResult();

            if (null === $user) {
                $message = sprintf(
                    'Unable to find an active admin AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                    $username
                );
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
            }

            return $user;
        }

        public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
        {
            $class = get_class($user);
            if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
                throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                    sprintf(
                        'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                        $class
                    )
                );
            }

            return $this->find($user->getId());
        }

        public function supportsClass($class)
        {
            return $this->getEntityName() === $class
                || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
        }
    }
```

Ok,
this Repository Query Class is actually the reason why it is not working.
After Debuging and Testing I came Along this Code Block in the Class:

Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    if (null !== $this->property) {
        $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(array($this->property => $username));
    } else {
        if (!$this->repository instanceof UserLoaderInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The Doctrine repository "%s" must implement Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface.', get_class($this->repository)));
        }

        $user = $this->repository->loadUserByUsername($username);
    }

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('User "%s" not found.', $username));
    }

    return $user;
}
```

It states that the Repository Class must be an instance of UserLoaderInterface.
But the Documentation from

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

states it is an Instance of UserProviderInterface.

so the Login fails as it is not the right Interface implemented.
The Documentation (Cookbook) has an old Information in it, or the Symfony Team just simply forgot about it. ^^(can happen)

Hope this helps someone ^^

Comment: So change `if (!$this->repository instanceof UserLoaderInterface) {` to `if (!$this->repository instanceof UserProviderInterface) {` and it fixes it?

Comment: I think if you configure security.yml to use a custom user provider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#modify-security-yml) then you won't have to fool around with the UserLoaderInterface nonsense.  Assuming your repository is mapped to the entity correctly then I don't see how the doctrine bridge code is even being called.

Comment: First comment: Not really. This is Symfony 3 Code and they changed the Interface for UserLoading for a Reson and I didn't want to modify and of the core Classes as this change would disapear with the next update.

Comment: Secpmd Comment.
This is true, but I am using some sub routines also.
I just wanted to share the stuff I found so other People, how might stumble on the migration over the same Problem like me, find a solution.
Just wanted to share it^^

Answer (score 5):

<del>UserProviderInterface</del> was changed to UserLoaderInterface in 2.8 ([see doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user))

- class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements
  <del>UserProviderInterface</del>
- class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
  implements **UserLoaderInterface**

This wil fix the problem, you can also delete these functions:

- <del>public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)</del>
- <del>public function supportsClass($class)</del>

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the isEqualTo method of the EquatableInterface (on my User entity) was returning false when it should have been returning true.